# Aligning input field with long input name

Tags: html, css

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk0ue.jpg)

Please check the image. I want to align the input field with the input field name, more in the central, right now the input field aligns on the same level of the input field name.

Following is the code

```
<div class="form-group basestations">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{% trans "Management Network IP Address" %}</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="mni_address" value="192.168.255.129" id = "addr" maxlength="20" required pattern="^(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?[1-9]|[0-1]?[1-9][0])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}$">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does this have a python tag?

Comment: i put it because i have this django tags in it.. but yeah python isnt necessary here

Comment: Where is your current CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the `.form-group .basestations` div `vertical-align: middle;`

This should align all the items in an element vertically in the middle. If this doesn't work, please tell me!

Quick test would be:

```
<div class="form-group basestations" style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{% trans "Management Network IP Address" %}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mni_address" value="192.168.255.129" id = "addr" maxlength="20" required pattern="^(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?[1-9]|[0-1]?[1-9][0])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}$">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks